# При отправке JSON на сервер символ '+' не приходит

Tags: json, swift

Я отправляю на сервер

```
     let jsonAddUserNumber : JSON = [
            "func" : "addUserNumber",
            "params" : [
            "auth_token" : "\(userToken)",
            "phone" : "+380990000000"
        ]
    ]

    let urlPath = urlPath
    let postString = "json_function=\(jsonAddUserNumber)"
    let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://myurl...")!
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    var dataa : NSData?
    let semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)

    request.HTTPBody = (postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding))
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request){ data, response, error in

        if error != nil{
            print("Error -> \(error!)")
            return
        }

        dataa = data!
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)

    }
    task.resume()


    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)

    let reply = NSString(data: dataa!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

в итоге на сервер номер приходит   **38099000000**

нужна помощь

Comment: попробуйте вывести postString и request.HTTPBody, посмотреть где оно теряется

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Когда сталкивался с подобной проблемой, решил таким способом:

```
let postString = "json_function=\(jsonAddUserNumber)".stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())!.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("+", withString: "%2B")
```

---

Из одного ответа на enSO достаточно

```
.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())!
```

но все-равно терялся + без `.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("+", withString: "%2B")`

Comment: Спасибо большое, всё работает, достаточно было добавить            '.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("+", withString: "%2B")'